# DDD – How to implement access to multi-language data in other bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design, multilingual, bounded-contexts

We are struggling with the integration of bounded contexts and multi-language text.

As part of a larger system we have an order bounded context and a warehouse bounded context. A user puts a product from a specific warehouse in the shopping cart. Some products can be customized at or after purchase (e.g. add a name or select the day for service execution). Therefore we use a purchase entity in the order context and a product entity in the warehouse context. The purchase entity holds the part of the information of the product (e.g. product name) that is necessary to handle the order, the customization information, and the IDs of the product and warehouse.

The product information is entered in multiple languages. For display of the shopping cart the warehouse context provides the purchasable list of products. There is an option to change language during the order. Also legal requirements can differ in various countries and the documents like invoices might need to be accessible and archived in the local language(s). Therefore order and documents like invoices shall be creatable/visible in different languages.

We are not sure how we shall handle the multi-language information in the purchase entity since this information comes from the warehouse context.

Option 1) Only save the ProductId in the purchase entity and re-query the language from the warehouse context each time it is needed.

This would allow to show documents also in languages that have been added later. In my opinion it would couple the contexts too much. I rather would like to have the order context be independent for reporting and archiving. When changing the display language in the UI the UI and the product information needs to be changed. Since the UI specific text is fixed it normally will be exchanged by the client via resource files (e.g. Angular as frontend). The product information is dynamic and therefore the client would need to re-query all displayed data from the backend. This means that discontinued products that have been ordered at least once never can be deleted from the warehouse context, because the data is needed for the display of the orders.

Option 2) Copy all available languages into the purchase entity.

This would make the order context independent for reporting and archiving. If the product information is also passed to the client in all supported languages a UI change would not need any call to the backend. With a few languages and not much product information this can work well, but most likely creates a performance issue with many languages. Also if a language will be added later it would not be automatically available.

There are two different concerns. One is the UI language change. The other is the communication between bounded contexts. If the client needs to query the backend for a UI change it is not a big issue, since it is not a frequent action. I'm more concerned that with option 1 for each action and display of the cart the order context needs to access the warehouse context and is fully dependent just to display the cart or an order document even nothing has changed. My main concern is the archiving and legal rules. If an order has been placed the data must stay unaltered. If an order is updated, products can be added or removed, but each one is a new order line. The previous data must remain unchanged. Therefore it feels not right to ask another bounded context that is not under control for data that must be unaltered. The only logical procedure to me is to create a copy in the order context.

A compromise solution could be to copy only the language the order is placed in plus eventually a different legal language into the purchase to fulfill requirements for unaltered data and archiving. If the order data wants to be viewed in a different language later the warehouse context can be queried.

Does anyone has experience with this problem? Is there a best practice for multi-language text exchange between bounded contexts and between context and UI? Is there an issue with our thinking of bounded contexts? Thanks for any help.

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

> Also legal requirements can differ in various countries and the documents like invoices might need to be accessable and archived in the local language(s).

This to me seems the only thing related to the domain, as business rules seems to be per COUNTRY not per language (places like Belgium speaks 3 main languages, you are interested in Belgium I think not in the language), so you need this in the purchase entity to let it achieve its business rules.

Issues related to the UI should be solved elsewhere, it doesn't seem to me correct to model an entity to improve UI concerns, you should solve that issue elsewhere.

Option 1 to me seems the correct thing to do, but I didn't understood your concerns too much

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The country is of course saved in the order. I tried to clarify my concerns and edited the text. 
To change the language of prodcut information in the UI is a domain requirement, so it needs to be reflected in the entity. The problem is not the language of the UI (buttons, etc.), but of the product information. Further the UI could be in a different language then the product information. E.g. I use an English UI, but the prodcut information is displayed in German. It might be that product information is not available in all UI languages or vice versa.

Comment: Ok, now I get a better view of the problem, a question came into my mind:  If I do an order with a single item, choosing my country/single language and complete it, archiving is done and everything is fine and completed for what regards my order. Then the product I ordered is update in the warehouse context, should the legal archived show what I saw when I bought the product or what it is now?

Comment: The legal archived must show what you saw when you purchased the product.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to me that you need to copy the data, doing at the moment it needs to be freezed (when the user "close" the order? what is the event that make the data freeze).
Now (as you pointed out) if new languages are created how can you show what the user saw in that language if it was not there at that time?
I'm wondering if for the use case of archiving and reporting it really needs to have the information available for ALL the languages, or just what the user was using (I'm not saying that it is not needed, but then new languages are really an issue from business rules perspective?)

Comment: One thing that usually helped me with this kind of situation, is reasoning in terms of paper.
How the domain expert would implement this using pen, paper and a copy machine? :)

Comment: To be able to show an invoice or an order in different languages after the order is completed I see two options:

1) copy all languages on the paper
2) have one language on the paper or a code and then other papers with the translations for each language/code.

Therefore I tended to option 2 in my post. I can either copy all languages into the purchase or I can copy all purchased products in the order context and link from the purchase to the current product version. This reduces storage space, but it requires versioning logic.

For languages only a translation table may be sufficient.